# How to capture values returned from a Python Class in Airflow Dag Script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I have a python class which actually returns a set of values ( two strings and a list ). I'd need to capture these values in Airflow Dag Script and populate the values into a dictionary later. It'd be great to know If anyone has come across a way to store the values returned from a Python class in `Airflow`?

For Eg I have a class X() and it has a method Y() which returns those 3 values. So can I do something like below to capture those values in `Airflow`?

```
x = X() 
val1, val2, val3 = x.Y() # to capture the values
```

Also what sort of an Airflow operator should I be using in order to achieve this ( like either Bash or Python operator )?

Comment: Please define "I want to store it in Airflow". Do you talk about Airflow variable?

Comment: yes @balderman I need to store those values in Airflow in 3 diff variables

Comment: By "populate the values into a dictionary later" you mean using those values in another task within the same DAG? If so, check [Xcoms](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use AirFlow [Varaible](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html)

```
d = {'x':'y'}
Variable.set('my_data_key',json.dumps(d))
```